# varchar and nvarchar are not supported in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, text, varchar, sqldatatypes, nvarchar

While creating table using pgAdmin (PostgreSQL UI), I could see that `name` are getting datatype as `text`. Which means in PostgreSQL there is no support for varchar and nvarchar ?

If so, please suggest what are the datatypes that will not supported by PostgreSQL comparing with other databases (SQL Server, My SQL, ORACLE) ?

Any help would be appreciated ... :)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-TABLE

Comment: `varchar` is most certainly supported, but `nvarchar` is not. Please read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle provided datatype comparison table for **oracle**, **mysql**, db2, ingres, **sql server**, firebird and **postgres**](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/oracle-guide/a-comparison-of-data-types-between-various-databases-oracle-mysql-db2-ingres-sql-server-firebird-postgres-33209)

Please concider reading documentation of each vendor as well.